# How to make URLs relative to the domain/server it is hosted on

Tags: javascript, html, url, hyperlink

I have a menu bar displaying various urls:

```
<a href="http://staging.subdomain.site.co.uk/search/page">Menu</a>
```

The source site is hosted on a different external subdomain served from an API service and I want to replace my host part of my URLS to be dynamic so testers can test the site whether they are on live, test or local server.

So the ideal outcome for the tester depending on which server is testing on will be:

```
<a href="http://staging.site.co.uk/page">Menu</a>

<a href="http://test.site.co.uk/page">Menu</a>

<a href="http://www.site.co.uk/page">Menu</a>
```

Comment: <a href="http://test.site.co.uk/page">Menu</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply needed this in the end `<a href="//<%=request.getServerName() %>/page">Link</a>`

Comment: Great! to see that you fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I might be thinking a little too simple, but...

```
<a href="/page">Menu</a>
```

If you are on `http://staging.site.co.uk/` the result will be `http://staging.site.co.uk/page` 
and on `http://test.site.co.uk/` it will actually be `http://test.site.co.uk/page`

Comment: Normally it is that simple. But my header file that has these navigation links (serves only a specific section of the site) is hosted externally from an API search service that resolves to the name  as an example   search.site.co.uk/search. so using only / will resolve to http://staging.search.site.co.uk/search/page